# Internet Explorer doesn't properly scale svg inside flex-box

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, scale

I have an inline svg with a viewBox. When the svg is wrapped in a div, which is then inside a flexbox, the dimensions are not calculated properly by IE(11). 
Here is a example of the issue:
HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 50 100">
          <path d="m0,-5 l40, 55 l-40,55" />
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;

  display: flex;

}


#main > div {

  height: 80%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Same code on JSbin:
[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pehahiqepi/1/edit?html,css,output)

On chrome for example, it works as expected. I need a responsive design, which works in IE too and since I am using bootstrap grid (which is just a flexbox) I need a solution for this. Thank you.